# Анимация в "Показать еще"

Tags: javascript, ajax

Помогите вставить анимацию в код подгрузки "Показать еще" (какую-то гифку или png не знаю что лучше)
и на время подгрузки скрыть или не скрывать фразу "Показать еще",
 а то без анимации не понятно сколько ждать и вообще происходит ли подгрузка.

Comment: Покажите работающий пример, а не кусок кода и вы просите сделать всё за вас?

Answer (score 1):

Разбираться в приведённом куске кода весьма сложно, приведу абстрактный пример, как работает подобный лоадер -  показано, припишете у себя в соответствии с контекстом.

```js
// Список постов (подгружаете через AJAX, вручную добавляете, неважно)
let posts = [
    'А я новый пост',
    'Свеж и горяч я',
    'Это последний'
  ],
  spinner = null,
  loadText = null,
  countPosts = null,
  wrapper = null;

function loadMore() {
  if (posts.length > 0) { // Если загружать есть что
    // Скрываем надпись и показываем анимацию
    loadText.style.display = 'none';
    spinner.style.display = 'block';

    // Поставил задержку (в реальности тут может быть ожидание AJAX, например), ибо иначе всё вставилось бы очень быстро
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Вставляем надпись и обновляем счётчик
      wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<div class='newPost'>${posts.shift()}</div>`);
      
      // Если больше нет записей, меняем надпись, иначе - счётчик.
      if(posts.length === 0)
        loadText.innerHTML = 'Hasta la vista, baby!';
      else
        countPosts.innerHTML = posts.length;

      // Показываем запись и скрываем анимацию
      loadText.style.display = 'block';
      spinner.style.display = 'none';
    }, 2000);
  }
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  // Ставим обработчик на кнопку "Подгрузить"
  document.querySelector('#loadMore').addEventListener('click', loadMore);

  spinner = document.querySelector('.cssload-square');
  loadText = document.querySelector('#loadMore');
  countPosts = document.querySelector('#countPosts');
  wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');

  // Сразу выводим количество доступных для показа записей
  countPosts.innerHTML = posts.length;
});
```

```css
#loadMore {
  display: block;
  background: #eff0f1;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#wrapper div {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.newPost {
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, .2);
}
.cssload-square {
  display: none;
}





.cssload-square {
  margin: 8px 20px;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.cssload-square-part {
  position: absolute;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: cssload-part-anim 0.92s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95) infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: cssload-part-anim 0.92s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95) infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: cssload-part-anim 0.92s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95) infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-part-anim 0.92s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95) infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: cssload-part-anim 0.92s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95) infinite alternate;
}
.cssload-square-green {
  background: rgb(84, 250, 212);
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  -o-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  -ms-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}
.cssload-square-pink {
  background: rgb(233, 111, 146);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.cssload-square-blend {
  background: rgb(117, 81, 125);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: blend-anim 0.92s ease-in infinite;
  -o-animation: blend-anim 0.92s ease-in infinite;
  -ms-animation: blend-anim 0.92s ease-in infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blend-anim 0.92s ease-in infinite;
  -moz-animation: blend-anim 0.92s ease-in infinite;
}
@keyframes blend-anim {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.01, 0.01) rotateY(0);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1, 1) rotateY(0);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.01, 0.01) rotateY(0);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes blend-anim {
  0% {
    -o-transform: scale(0.01, 0.01) rotateY(0);
    -o-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715);
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateY(0);
    -o-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: scale(0.01, 0.01) rotateY(0);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes blend-anim {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: scale(0.01, 0.01) rotateY(0);
    -ms-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateY(0);
    -ms-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: scale(0.01, 0.01) rotateY(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blend-anim {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.01, 0.01) rotateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateY(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.01, 0.01) rotateY(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes blend-anim {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.01, 0.01) rotateY(0);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1) rotateY(0);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.01, 0.01) rotateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes cssload-part-anim {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-10px, -10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes cssload-part-anim {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translate3d(-10px, -10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes cssload-part-anim {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-10px, -10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssload-part-anim {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, -10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes cssload-part-anim {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-10px, -10px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(10px, 10px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id='loadMore'>Подгрузить ещё записи (<span id='countPosts'>0</span>)</span>
  <div class="cssload-square">
    <div class="cssload-square-part cssload-square-green"></div>
    <div class="cssload-square-part cssload-square-pink"></div>
    <div class="cssload-square-blend"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div>Существующий текст</div>
  <div>Я тоже тут</div>
</div>
```